# Unable to connect cqlsh in Cassandra 2.2.0

Tags: cqlsh

I am trying to launch cqlsh for the first time but I am getting the following error.

> ./cqlsh us01u256 9160
>     File "./cqlsh.py", line 625
>       ssl_options=sslhandling.ssl_settings(hostname, CONFIG_FILE) if ssl else None,
>                                                                    ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have checked the RPC Port : 9160 is accepting connections.

Not sure what is wrong or what is missing in the config files.

Comment: I have also check the CQL port 9042 it is up and accepting connections too.but the error is same.  netstat -an | grep 9042
tcp        0      0 172.19.32.146:9042          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
[oracle@us01u265:/h01/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.0/bin]$./cqlsh 172.19.32.146 9042
  File "./cqlsh.py", line 625
    ssl_options=sslhandling.ssl_settings(hostname, CONFIG_FILE) if ssl else None,
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's your Python version (python --version) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this connectivity issue by using the foll. command.  ./cqlsh localhost 9042 --cqlversion=3.3.0.

The earlier error message which I got was misleading.

Let me know if this helps, in case if you are in same situation.

Thanks
Ramesh.